# Get ID of child element of clicked element jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to build a small application where you are able to edit a row of a table as you click on it.  It's part of a greater AJAX-driven CRUD application but I can't seem to get it right.  My current jQuery code is as follows for this one section:

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit_tr", function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var split = ID.split('_');
$("#first_"+split[1]).hide();
$("#last_"+split[1]).hide();
$("#first_input_"+split[1]).show();
$("#last_input_"+split[1]).show();

}).change(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var split = ID.split('_');
var first=$("#first_input_"+split[1]).val();
var last=$("#last_input_"+split[1]).val(); });
```

I know that by clicking on the TR element (which is part of the body) it registers the event, but how can I get the ID of the clicked TR within that element?  I tried the following, and it works with pre-existing records, but it won't work with pre-existing rows, but it won't work on rows that were just added from the CRUD application.

```
$(".edit_tr").click(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var split = ID.split('_');
$("#first_"+split[1]).hide();
$("#last_"+split[1]).hide();
$("#first_input_"+split[1]).show();
$("#last_input_"+split[1]).show();

}).change(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var split = ID.split('_');
var first=$("#first_input_"+split[1]).val();
var last=$("#last_input_"+split[1]).val(); });
```

Edit: Here is the row I am dynamically adding each time I add a record:

```
    <tr id="item_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr"> 
<td class="edit_td"> 
<span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $firstname; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" size="8" class="editbox" id="first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: `this` inside the delegated handler is still the bound element, in your case `.edit_tr` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the ID of the child element clicked (from body, in this case it would be .edit_tr).

Comment: And inside the event handler that would be `this`

Comment: In the first block of code that you show, `this` will refer to the element with class "edit_tr", just like you want. That is, that code should work. Are you sure the rows you are dynamically adding have `id` attributes?

Comment: <tr id="item_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">
<td class="edit_td">
<span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $firstname; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" size="8" class="editbox" id="first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" />
</td>
</tr>

Yes.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYxbq/) showing the delegated event handler work.

Comment: Ok, why is it not doing that for me?  It keeps looking for the ID of the body tag, in my case "undefined."